# Automated testing web application

Tags: testing, selenium, jenkins, casperjs

I am looking for a tool to functionally test my **Yii**/ **Node.js** web application. The first thing I looked into was **Selenium**. The app runs on a headless Ubuntu server so successfully setting up **xvfb** and run a test was really painfull and drove me to another tool. 
The error I kept getting is:

```
Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display :0
```

The other tool was [Casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) along with [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) . Aside from the 5 minute setting up, I wrote few tests and integrated all with Jenkins CI. I really believe there should be more tools like this one. So I feel I've earned something on the short term, but I'm afraid that on the long term I'll hit a dead end. Could you give me some feedback? Am I going the wrong road?

Another thing that's crossing my mind is to setup the Selenium RC and Jenkins on a Windows machine with all browsers set up. I think this will give my tests a better and more accurate perspective.

*** I would also like to be able to do some parallel functional tests (interactions) since the website is socket-driven. Does Selenium handle that?

Comment: waiting for the bounty..

Comment: Happy to hear you like Casper (author here)

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use Selenium RC if you can avoid it, it's officially deprecated in favor of Selenium Webdriver (also known as Selenium 2).

About headlessness - Webdriver can be easily run on top of [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and also [PhantomJS](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) - both should work right away.

If you want to run the tests on actual browsers, people have been successful in running that on headless systems, too, but as you said, it's a pain. Instead, you can run the tests remotely on a different machines with your headless server commanding them all.

Comment: I'll happily elaborate on any further questions, fire away!